# The right verb for when we want others' trust for a longer time?

Tags: word-request

What is the right verb for when we want others' trust for a longer time. Do we want to keep their trust, to retain their trust, to preserve their trust, ... ?

Example:

> By saying only the truth I can ... their trust far longer.

Comment: I'd use *win their trust...*

Comment: You are, anyway, using 'for a long time..' in the example, so there is no *question* of asking for a verb that replaces 'long term.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Keep***, ***retain***, or probably most synonyms for those, all work naturally. That's assuming that the speaker either already has their trust, or is describing a situation in which they will already have their trust.

Comment: What do you mean by "they will already have their trust"?